# Java: Access class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, class

I'm loading all the players from a database into the class `Player`, this happens in the class `DB`.

```
// class DB
 ArrayList<Player> player= new ArrayList();

    public void loadPlayers() {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM players");
        while (rs.next()) {
            player.add(new Player(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("score"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("error selecting");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}


// class Player
    int id, score;
    String name;

    public Customer(int id, String name, int score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName(int id) {
        return name;
    }


// View
// do i need here something like "ArrayList<Player> player"?

  DB.INSTANCE.loadPlayers(); // I use the Singleton pattern
  System.out.println(player.getName(5));
```

How can I access the class `Player` from other classes besides DB?
For example I want to call the method `player.getName(5);` from `View` and get its particular name.
Do I have to load all the players in something like an Array or an ArrayList?

Comment: I have updated the code. But it still doesn't work...  I get a `NullPointerException` at `System.out.println(player.getName(5));`

Comment: The hell -- four answers, not one upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a `Collection` of `Player`.

```
while (rs.next()) {
   player = new Player(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("score"));
}
```

will only hold the last retrieved player from the database, because there's only one member in your class.

If you want something like `DB.getName(5)`, I'd suggest a `HashMap<Integer,Player>` member, that way lookup by id will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DB` class needs to have not a `Player` variable, but a *collection* of `Player` -- i.e., `List<Player>`. Then, you can simply have a method that returns that collection, or a copy of the collection, so that other classes have access to it.

Comment: How do I call this collection, say `ArrayList<Player>` (defined in `DB`) from another class, e.g. `View`?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're loading each player into the same member variable in `DB`, which isn't very useful. You should create a method in `DB` which returns a `List` of `Player`. Construct an `ArrayList` in this method and do something like this inside your loop:

```
players.add(new Player(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("score")));
```

Then, from your view layer, you can do something like this:

```
DB db = new DB();
for (Player p : db.getPlayers())
    System.out.println(p.getName());
```

**Updated**

**DB**

```
public class DB {

    ...

    private static DB instance;

    public static DB getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DB();
        return instance;
    }

    public List<Player> loadPlayers() {
         List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
         try {
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM players");
             while (rs.next()) {
                 players.add(new Player(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("score"));
             }
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println("error selecting");
             System.err.println(ex);
         }
         return players;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public class View {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        List<Player> players = db.loadPlayers();
        for (Player p : players)
            System.out.println(p.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I have to define Player in `View`?

Comment: No, `Player` should be a separate class in your project, i.e. `Player.java`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's an own class. I mean, `View` doesn't know `Player`, so do I have to define an instance of it in `View`?

Comment: No, the view will know the `Player` class once it's imported.

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have it set up, yes, you need to save off the players list in view. It would make more sense to have the loadPlayers method return a list, and then use that value to set a list in View.

Comment: `DB`: `public ArrayList loadPlayser()` ... `return player`  and `View`: `ArrayList<Players> player` ... `player.addAll(DB.INSTANCE.loadPlayers())`. How to call a method from `Player` now?

Comment: Iterate through the array list using a for loop "for (Player player : players) { // do stuff };" Or, "players.get(0).callMethodOnPlayer();"